# How to use the Javascript File API in React JS to upload a local file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, firebase, firebase-storage

Lets say I have a photo in ./profile-logo.svg that I want to upload to firebase storage. Right now that part of my code looks like this:

```
import profileLogo from './profile-logo.svg';
...
var file = new File(profileLogo);
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var propicRef = storageRef.child(`propics/${currentUser.uid}/${file.name}`);
var uploadTask = propicRef.put(file);
```

This gives the error `undefinedFailed to construct 'File': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.` I find the documentation a bit unclear about the 'bits' and 'name' arguments.

What I have working: uploading to firebase from a `<input type="file"/>` component

Links for reference:
JS File Constructor documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/File
Firebase storage upload file: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files

EDIT: when I try sending in a string for the second argument like `var file = new File(profileLogo, "propic.svg");`, I get an alert that says `Failed to construct 'File': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.`

Comment: What do you find unclear exactly? This constructor requires at least two arguments, the first one being a sequence of data (e.g an Array containing your string), and the second one being the file name i.e a string to which the File object's `.name` property will be set. But are you sure you actually even need a File? Wouldn't a Blob be enough? Browser support for File constructor is not that great (some implementations have serious bugs with it...)

Comment: @Kaiido If I just change the word 'File' to 'Blob' in code above, I get a similar error (see edit) `Failed to construct 'Blob': The provided value cannot be converted to a sequence.` I am confused about what the constructor is expecting and how to get my file into the form that it is expecting. How do I create an Array of ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, or DOMString objects from what I have? Is it not possible with just the filepath?

Comment: "*a sequence of data (e.g an Array containing your string)*" => `[profileLogo]` => `new File([profileLogo], 'filename.svg')`. But note that `profileLogo` is not the *filepath*, it is the actual data contained in your file (and I hope `import profileLogo from './profile-logo.svg';` does return the markup of this svg file...)